# Google drive api with one user account for different devices

Tags: android, google-drive-android-api

I am working with google drive API to backup and restore my SQLite database. All works perfect. But now i have a problem.

For example a user with id xyz@gmail.com login from two different devices to access my app. Now if both the device runs simultaneously only last device update will be saved on drive.

How can i restrict user to use only one google account per device? For ex. i have xyz@gmail account and i use this account with two devices.

How can i handle this? Please guide me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the user connect with his account, you set a boolean to false in db, when he disconnect/leave the app you set the boolean to true.

When he log in, you check the value of the boolean, if true he can connect, otherwise you block him.

Comment: i am sorry but i am not getting you...can you please elaborate?

Comment: You create a boolean in database in order to know if he is already connected on another device. If he isnt then he can access the app, if he is you refuse the connection

Comment: but how can i determine he is connected to other device?

Comment: When he connect you set the boolean to true in database. 

Then when he try to log in on another device, you check the boolean, if the boolean is true that means he is connected on another device. If he is false, that means he isnt connected on another device.

Comment: Then you should explicit, cause what i explain totally solve the problem of the same account connected on 2 device simultaneously

Answer (score 0):

save the users device id at login time, then you can manage which user using one account on two device.